# What happened to people in unsafe areas during the Blip?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame, spider-man-far-from-home

We've seen in *Spider-Man: Far From Home* that

> The Blip made the Snapped people appear where they where at the moment of the Snap.

But what happened to the people who were on a plane? Do they appear in the sky as the plane is not there anymore? Or do they appear in the plane where they were, wherever the plane is?

With the same idea, what happened if there's concrete (for example) where they were snapped? Like a new building has been created.

Do the *Infinity Stones* know how to Blip people in such cases?

Comment: I wouldn't look at it as going back to the same spot exactly, or you could take it even further and say 'the earth moved during these years, would they appear in space?'

Comment: @MorZamir They obviously go back to the exact same spot relative to the planet normally as we see the band appear in the basketball court where they were Snapped and when Peter tells Tony in _Endgame_ it is like he appears back in the same spot again.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Jon Watts, the director for *Spider-Man: Far From Home* touched on this a bit in a few interviews and whilst he mainly avoids answering the question he does state that they would be Blipped back safely.

> “What would happen to people in motion, if you’re in a car or in an airplane?” said the director. “Obviously, they didn’t blip back in the middle of the sky and fall to the Earth because so many people would die.”
>
> Watts said, “There are so many questions, but we just stuck with the ones that made sense in our story.”
>
> So what would happen to people who came back who were previously in an airplane?
>
> “I was like, you know what, I’m not going to touch that one,” Watts joked, explaining the idea was really that everyone came back in one piece.
>
> “That’s the thing. Everyone arrived back safely somehow. I don’t think suddenly people were raptured back to Earth and plummeted into the ocean. That would not be the happy ending that [Tony Stark] was planning.”
>
> <sub>[HuffPost, 'Spider-Man: Far From Home' Director Sets Record Straight On 'Plot Hole'](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/spider-man-far-from-home-plot-hole_n_5d092bc8e4b06ad4d2572561)</sub>

Kevin Feige, the president of Marvel Studios, had previously answered this question as well during a AMA on reddit. He again states the people would be brought back safely.

> **dwallace3099:** People have expressed views that, in Endgame, those brought back by the snap could have died in accidents (like someone being brought back 100 ft in the air where a plane used to be). Is it possible that Hulk, when doing the snap, not only brought everyone back, but also brought them back in a safe place?
>
> **KevFeige:** We refer to the version of Hulk in Endgame as Smart Hulk. So, yes.
>
> <sub>[reddit, r/marvelstudios, Hi reddit, I'm Kevin Feige. AMAA](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bp084n/hi_reddit_im_kevin_feige_amaa/ennasj9/)</sub>

Comment: Mind you, none of them have paid their rents/mortgages in 5 years, so they're probably all homeless.  And many of them are probably broke - banks don't necessarily keep accounts open for people who are presumed dead with no surviving family.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman May in FFH runs a charity dedicated to those displaced by the Blip and May/Peter themselves were also displaced by it.

Comment: Oops.  Guess I should stay away from the internet until I'm caught up on the movie then...

Comment: Don't forget the issue where suddenly the earth needs to produce food for 2x its current population... I'm sure that would go well.

Comment: @Domenic the Snap affected all life, animal populations and farm stock would also double over night. You’d have a brief period of rationing but it’d get back to normal soon enough.

Answer (score 5):

An in universe answer to go with what the director/writers/other intended: when any of the snaps happened the wielder of the stones was not expressing exactly what would happen to every individual in the universe, but was concentrating on an overall intention which the stones read, interpreted, and bent the universe to implement.

Thanos didn't specify in detail which life to take, he may not have specified the dusting organisms in any way, just "half of all sentient life is to go".

Similarly, Smart Hulk probably just thought something along the lines of "bring everyone who went back safely", and the stones interpreted that intent, bringing most back to exactly where they were (presumably the least complicated path) and those who would not be safe to a similar but different point (standing on the deck of a different plane, or on the lap of the person in the equivalent seat, or at one of the airports on their journey, for in-flight examples).

Of course that still leaves some questions and problems: what about those killed indirectly by the snap, those hit by suddenly driver-less cars and so forth (I assume they are still gone, though there is nothing stated in the films to support either way) and there would be complications with such as planes suddenly being over their designed carrying capacity. I doubt Hulk's snap was perfect.

Comment: Thanos' Snap killed half of *all* life, not just sentient life.

Comment: @Martha which means the snap must have caused widespread ecological collapase and extinctions, and the blip probably didn't fix it.

(Imagine a species going from 100% to 50%, then 50% to 0% because of collapse.. then 50% come back. Then they die out. For example: species of bird that have a mate for life might not bounce back).

Comment: @JBChouinard: yes. Basically, the whole "snap-unsnap five years later" conceit does not stand up to close scrutiny. I mean, what about people who come back to find their spouse has remarried? What about people who come back to houses that have sat unoccupied for the last half-decade, and are now not exactly habitable? What about the people who disappeared from critical jobs, like nuclear reactor operators? How did those reactors not fail catastrophically? I could go on...

Comment: _"Thanos didn't specify in detail which life to take"_ - it appears he did have more control than you seem to think. He seems to have excluded himself and Tony and he probably excluded those races he'd already culled.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - fair point, though while he may have had specific individuals in mind, he would not have had specific intentions beyond those few individuals.